# Implementing Calculator History

Tags: asp.net

The following code is a fully functioning ASP.NET calculator. How can I keep the history of all calculations entered even if the user closes the browser?  For example, if the user enters 5+10, I need it to show 15 after I close and open the program again.

Also, is there a way to display the history of all calculations over the last 10 minutes?

```
<script runat="server">

sub getvalue0(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn0.Text

end sub



sub getvalue1(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn1.Text

end sub



sub getvalue2(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn2.Text

end sub



sub getvalue3(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn3.Text

end sub



sub getvalue4(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn4.Text

end sub



sub getvalue5(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn5.Text

end sub



sub getvalue6(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn6.Text

end sub



sub getvalue7(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn7.Text

end sub



sub getvalue8(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn8.Text

end sub



sub getvalue9(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=txtinput.Text & btn9.Text

end sub



sub check(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

val1.Text=txtinput.Text

txtinput.Text=""

end sub



sub sum(s as Object, E as EventArgs)

val2.Text=txtinput.Text

dim result=cInt(val1.Text)+cInt(val2.Text)

txtinput.Text=result

end sub



sub clear(s as Object, e as EventArgs)

txtinput.Text=""

val1.Text=""

val2.Text=""

end sub



</script>



<html>

<title> Basic Calculator</title>

<body>



<form id="Form1" runat="server">

<h1>Basic Calculator</h1>

<asp:TextBox id="txtinput" runat="server" />

<table style="background:#00ffff">

<tr>

<td><asp:Button id="btn0" Text="0" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue0" /></rd>

<td><asp:Button id="btn1" Text="1" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue1" /></rd>

<td><asp:Button id="btn2" Text="2" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue2"/></rd>



<td><asp:Button id="btnsum" Text="+" runat="server" OnClick="check"/></rd>

</tr>

<td><asp:Button id="btn3" Text="3" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue3" /></rd>

<td><asp:Button id="btn4" Text="4" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue4"/></rd>

<td><asp:Button id="btn5" Text="5" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue5"/></rd>



<td><asp:Button id="btnequal" Text="=" runat="server" OnClick="sum" /></rd>

</tr>

<td><asp:Button id="btn6" Text="6" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue6"/></rd>

<td><asp:Button id="btn7" Text="7" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue7"/></rd>

<td><asp:Button id="btn8" Text="8" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue8"/></rd>



<td><asp:Button id="btnclear" Text="Clear" runat="server" OnClick="clear"/></rd>

</tr>

<tr><td><asp:Button id="btn9" Text="9" runat="server" OnClick="getvalue9"/></td></tr>

</table>

<asp:Textbox id="val1" Visible="false" runat="server"/>

<asp:Textbox id="val2" visible="false" runat="server"/>



</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to decide where you want to store the data. Cookie, Database, local storage. That will lead to your implementation

Comment: I would like to use cookies.

Comment: And you want to save the value on any button click or just the action ones like SUM

Comment: Any button would be best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to persist after closing the browser you are going to need to persist the data somewhere like a database, or file.

You could try storing in the session but depending how you have your site setup this has no gurantee for how long it will be around for (see the different types of sessions modes for more information).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new function called something like SetText. You will call this method from all the other event handlers with the value to set.

```
sub setText(s as String)

  Dim myCookie As New HttpCookie("calculatorValue")
  myCookie.Value = s
  myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
  Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)

  txtinput.Text= s

end sub
```

Then, on your page's pageload event. You can set the textbox if necessary

```
sub PageLoad()

    Dim cookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("calculatorValue")
    if (txtimput.Text == "" && cookie != null && cookie.Value != "")
    {
         txtinput.Text = cookie.Value;

         //Clear out cookie
    }
```

That might not be 100% cause I didn't test but should be pretty close.

Comment: Wouldn't the cookie value be `s` and not `"True"`?

Comment: sub PageLoad() is not working. (after I fixed 'txtimput') I am getting "'cookie' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."  My option is to generate class 'cookie' but this does not fix the error.

Comment: You guys are both correct, quick typing = errors. I have cookie in there an extra time and was setting it to the wrong thing :-)

Comment: I implemented the code with no errors but for some reason the cookies are not working.  Could this be due to running the app on localhost?

Comment: They should still work ok running off localhost. Can you inspect your cookies and see if any are created?